# Hibernate Inheritance: Two children sharing a parent

Tags: java, hibernate

I have a simple JOINED hierarchy of persons:

```
@Entity
@Inheritance(strategy=InheritanceType.JOINED)
@Table(name="person")
public class Person implements Serializable

@Entity
@Table(name="student")
@PrimaryKeyJoinColumn(name="id")
public class Student extends Person

@Entity
@PrimaryKeyJoinColumn(name="id")
@Table(name="teacher")
public class Teacher extends Person
```

Is it possible to have a person who is a teacher and a student at the same time?

Answer (score 0):

I'm inclined to suggest that you add a field for teacher that indicates studentship without altering the defined hierarchy. i.e.

```
@Entity
@PrimaryKeyJoinColumn(name="id")
@Table(name="teacher")
@Table(isStudent="True/False")
public class Teacher extends Person
```

Alternatively, have you considered making a third class representing a Teacher who is also a Student, as an extension of Person?

```
@Entity
@PrimaryKeyJoinColumn(name="id")
@Table(name="teacher-student")
public class TeacherStudent extends Person
```

Comment: Does this answer help you at all?